# Ritual/symbolism of putting teapot in cup

Tags: eat-drink-man-woman, analysis

In [Eat, drink, man, woman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111797/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (Yin shi nan nu, 1994), at 1:44, one of the daughters pours hot water out of a large pot into a tiny one, then pours the tea out of the tiny pot, then puts that one in the cup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

She is in a teahouse, having a conversation with the man she thought a love affair was developing with, but who  (the day before) turned out to be married already:

> Thanks for coming. I thought you might not show up.
>   Why not?
>   The other night... 
>   ... (interrupted by waitress)
>   (First pouring)
>   I understand what you've been going through... although I can't explain it.
>   Neither can I...
>   It's complicated, but I can understand that.
>   Thanks.
>   (Second pouring and putting the small pot in)

I can't help thinking that this is a ritual and/or symbolic for what's going on.
Can anyone explain the symbolim of this last gesture?

Comment: In some area people first clean the plate,spoon,teapot and other things with some sort of water before serving food in it from hotels. Seen some videos on that.